# Flutter best way for splash / loading screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app connected to firebase (firestore).

When the user opens the app, I check if he's a user type 1 or user type 2. + load images from the web etc.

But it takes maybe a second to do all these things.
What's the best way to make / implement a loading screen / splash screen that shows up until everything is loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#updating-the-launch-screen ?

Comment: It depends if you mean the delay between app launch and flutter loading its first view or loaded application and loading content from api. Splash screen should only be displayed when loading the app - (white/grey) background when an app is opened. For the second case you can use FutureBuilder and use CircularProgressIndicator class to display loading animation. You can also use some other animation or any other widget to be displayed while loading data from the Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to define a Widget that will display a loading animation and will do some backgroundwork at the same time.

The widget takes a widget that represents the "loading animation" and a function that will be executed in the background.

This is taken from https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter.

You can find a documentation at https://ez-flutter.de/docs/transition

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

///
/// Widget for displaying loading animation and doing background work at the same time.
///
class EzTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  EzTransition(this.child, this.toProcess, {this.backgroundColor});

  final Function() toProcess;
  final Widget child;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  @override
  _EzTransitionState createState() => _EzTransitionState();
}

class _EzTransitionState extends State<EzTransition> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.toProcess();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: getBackgroundColor(),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  Color getBackgroundColor() {
    return widget.backgroundColor == null
        ? Theme.of(context).backgroundColor
        : widget.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you compute the background work?

Comment: I agree with @ChristianFindlay in running the background task in an  isolate, the task might be an expensive type. But the solution is top-notch anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

One of the way to do this is using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). The code snippet that I used in my application is given below

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _getData(), // the function to get your data from firebase or firestore
    builder : (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap){
        if(snap.data == null){
            //return loading widget
        }
        else{
            //return the widget that you want to display after loading
        } 
    }
);
```

The [AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) is returned by the function in "future" i.e. in this case _getData().

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Splashscreen`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_splash_screen) plugin, which offers `seconds` to delay routing to the next page so you can perform your checks, it also has a `navigateAfterSeconds` which you can write your condition in.

Example:

```
SplashScreen(
  seconds: 3,
  navigateAfterSeconds: HomePage(),
  title: Text('Splash'),
  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),),
  image: Image.asset('assets/images/icon2.png',),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  styleTextUnderTheLoader: TextStyle(),
  photoSize: 100.0,
  loaderColor: Colors.blue,
  loadingText: Text('initializing...'),
)
```

Comment: Better be **careful with third party plugins. Use them as sparse as possible!** Sooner or later you'll find yourself using a discontinued third party plugin - it just happens over time. Once a discontinued plugin becomes incompatible with the latest Flutter version, you're either stuck with an old Flutter version, or you'll fix the plugin, or migrate your project. Frustration and suddenly appearing unnecessary work are a certain side effect of excessive third party plugin reliance. Better be reluctant when it comes to using them.

Comment: There exists a chance that you need to update your own code too, and then you are completely unfamiliar with the code that you have written 2 months ago. It's no difference from using a third party plugin, except you could've skipped the first time implementation. You are basically saying, "Maybe I should write my own Linux distro (or even a new Unix-like kernel) instead of third party, because sometimes in the future the third party distro might be out-dated"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best option, as you don't know exactly how much time it will take is a [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) which will display a loading animation while you are loading

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [Ashish Shirgave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61310012/416586) when you're only loading local images and want to pre-load them, is to use  Future.wait() + precacheImage() + snap.connectionState.

eg.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
   future: Future.wait([
      precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/imageA.png"), context),
      precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/imageB.png"), context),
   ]),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
       if (snap.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting) {
           return Center(AssetImage("assets/imageA.png"));
       } else {
           return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
       }
   });
```